# How can I set and save background color for some item in the ListView, when the user clicks on it?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, background-color

I would like to change some item background color in my listview, when the user clicks on it. Furthermore, I want to save this in the shared preferences. I useing adapter for ListView. How can I do ?

My CategoryAdapter class:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mResource;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Category> categories) {
        super(context,resource,categories);

        mResource = resource;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        View view = convertView == null ? mInflater.inflate( mResource, parent, false ) : convertView;
        TextView categoryTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.name );

        Category item = getItem( position );

        categoryTitle.setText( item.getCategoryTitle() );

        return view;
    }

}
```

Where I want to use it:

```
CategorylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {

             }
        });
```

CategorylistView:

```
CategorylistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,category){
           @Override
           public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
 if(catViewPreferences.getInt("scn",0)==position){
                   textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
               }
return textView;
           }
       });
```

OnItemClickListener:

```
CategorylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {

                final String category = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                final String email = loginPreferences.getString("email","");
                final String password = loginPreferences.getString("password", "");

                final int position =  adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();

                if(i<8) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue));
                }

                catViewPrefEditor.putInt("scn", position);
                catViewPrefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: You want to change the color of that item you clicked on?

Comment: @Mohammad Zarei Yes, the background color.

Comment: Have you tried using a state list drawable as a background? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Comment: @pantos27, Not yet, how can I do with this?

Comment: Why aren't you using the CategoryAdapter class you created in CategorylistView.setAdapter?

Comment: @pantos27 I don`t know that, -how- shoud I do ... Can you help me?

Comment: @pantos27 Thank you, I understand this. However, the most important question is that, how can I save the tagged rows ?

Comment: @Storg what info do you want to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by changing the background of the `view` on `onItemClick` method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
          view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     }
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to deselect items, you can change the top method like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
          if(((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor() == Color.Blue){
              //the item is selected...now u must deselect it
              view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
          } else {
              view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
          }
     }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It works well, but how can I save these views, like string in the shared preferences? Actually, I would like to show these items with background color , which user clicked on,  again, when the application closed, and launched again.

Comment: I tryed to save onItemClick with this: final int position =  adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();

Comment: How can I unselect?

Comment: It's easy....just change the color back to what it was.....and check if the current color is different from the default color....I'll update my answer to show you how do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a state list Drawable
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

in your layout file specify a drawable file that will look something like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_focused"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_default"/>
</selector>
```

then in the `button_bg_selected` file write something like this

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners  android:radius="22px"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

To use the custom adapter you made

```
CategorylistView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,categories));
```

Comment: I just want to save these items background color, which clicked on the user. If the application closed and launched again.

Comment: Where will the color list come from in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, but I don`t understand the question.

Comment: give each button a number and put it in your shared preferences as an int

Comment: So I need to make 8 preferences, which I take int number (position from listview). Furthermore i need to make  8 if cycle for retrieve and show these items background?

Comment: I tryed to save this position in onItemClick method, in the sharedpreferences, and retrieve in View  with this condition:   if(catViewPreferences.getInt("scn",0)==position){
                   textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
               } , but it doesn't work

Comment: How did you put the int there?

Comment: CategorylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {  final int position =  adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();

                if(i<8) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue));
                }

                catViewPrefEditor.putInt("scn", position);
                catViewPrefEditor.commit();

Comment: I changed the post to how looks now.